# How can I remove * after numeric values in r

Tags: r

I have a list of values of runs scored by a batsmen in cricket  ( 2, 45, 55*, 50, 16). * indicates a 'NOT OUT' . How do I remove the * from the list ?

Comment: `sub('*', '', x, fixed = TRUE)`

Comment: And adding `as.numeric()` like `as.numeric(sub("*", "", x, fixed = TRUE))` will give you a vector of numeric values.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply go:

`runs_scored<-c("2","45","55*","50","16")
runs_scored_ok<-gsub('\\*','', runs_scored)`